Dimension of Nullspace of Adjoint
In finite-dimensional linear algebra, a linear operator mapping from a vector space to itself certainly has the same dimensional nullspace as does its Hermitian adjoint, per the rank nullity theorem. I'm interested in learning whether this result extends to linear differential operators acting on infinite-dimensional vector spaces. As I understand it, per the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem (I think all the operators I care about are elliptic) this amounts to calculating the topological index of the operator. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that.
The domain I'm interested in is real three-vector valued functions on the two-torus that are smooth and well-behaved.
I'd also be interested to learn whether there's any way to get information about the nullspace of the adjoint operator beyond its dimension from information about the nullspace of the original operator, but I suspect there isn't.

I think that you are looking for the so-called Fredholm index of the operator, i.e. the difference between dimension of the kernel and the co-kernel. In chapter 2 of https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6995-7 this is discussed in the context of PDEs.

Thanks, @C.Hamster ! I agree, the Fredholm index does seem to be what I want. I'm looking through the reference you sent, but I don't see how to calculate this. Do you have any further thoughts?

There are as far as I know no general approaches. There is example 2.2.2 in the book, and for the sturm-liouville operators coming from the linearised reaction-diffusion equations, you can compute a lot explicitly, but computing Fredholm properties of linear operators is a whole science on its own.
